# C# Pass multiple arguments to function and array

Tags: c#, arrays, function, webserver

I'm trying to start my "webserver" on all local IP's. So I have to send a string to `WebServer ws = new WebServer(SendResponse, IPs.GetIPs("program"));`, and a Array to `static string[] uris`.

Now it only receives one IP, tried some other ways like sending a string to `WebServer ws = new WebServer(SendResponse, IPs.GetIPs("program"));` but that also didn't work with multiple IP's.

It needs to return a `string` for `program` and a array for `webserver`.

The string should be something like this: "http://192.168.0.107:1337/", "http://192.168.56.1:1337/" for `program`.

How would I send more then 1 argument to a function and to a array. I know this code doesn't work but I'm desperate right now to get this working.

IPs.cs:

```
public static string GetIPs(string args)
    {
        string[] combinedString = { };
        List<string> IPAdressenLijst = new List<string>();
        IPAddress[] ips = Dns.GetHostAddresses(Dns.GetHostName());

        foreach (IPAddress ip in ips)
        {
            if (ip.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
            {
                if (args == "program")
                {
                    IPAdressenLijst.Add("http://" + ip + ":1337/");
                    combinedString = IPAdressenLijst.ToArray();
                }
                else if (args == "webserver")
                {
                    IPAdressenLijst.Add("http://" + ip + ":1337/start/");
                    IPAdressenLijst.Add("http://" + ip + ":1337/stop/");
                    combinedString = IPAdressenLijst.ToArray();
                }
            }
        }
        return combinedString[0];
    }
```

Program.cs:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now + " Press any key to exit.");
        //WebServer ws = new WebServer(SendResponse, "http://192.168.0.107:1337/", "http://localhost:1337/");
        WebServer ws = new WebServer(SendResponse, IPs.GetIPs("program"));
        ws.Run();
        Console.ReadKey();
        ws.Stop();
    }

public static string SendResponse(HttpListenerRequest request)
{
    return string.Format("TEST");
}
```

WebServer.cs:

```
public class WebServer
{
    //static string[] uris =
    //{
    //    "http://192.168.0.107:1337/start/",
    //    "http://192.168.0.107:1337/stop/"
    //};
    static string[] uris =
    {
        IPs.GetIPs("webserver")
    };
}
```

Comment: I think you can start it on `http://0.0.0.0:1337`. `0.0.0.0` is `IPAddress.Any`

Comment: what do you mean by sending string into an array? you don't send string into array, you would fill string array by some strings and you can send that array into a function.

Comment: If `GetIPs` is supposed to return an array, it should be `public static string[] GetIPs( string args )` and inside , get rid of `[0]` : `return combinedString;`

Comment: It needs to return a `string` for `program` and a `array` for `webserver`. Should I make 2 functions? The `string` should be something like this: `"http://192.168.0.107:1337/", "192.168.56.1:1337/"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start a `TcpListener` (for your webserver) you can use the `IPAddress.Any` address like below:

```
var server = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, port);
```

Now, to your code: The `GetIPs` function has bunch of issues. While you loop, you keep overwriting `combinedString`, every time. To top it, you actually just return the first item from `combinedString`. From the context of the question, I gather that you want to return all IP addresses and not just one

This is how that function should be

```
public static List<string> GetIPs(string args) {
    var ipAdressenLijst = new List<string>();
    IPAddress[] ips = Dns.GetHostAddresses(Dns.GetHostName());

    foreach (IPAddress ip in ips) {
        if (ip.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork) {
            if (args == "program") {
                ipAdressenLijst.Add("http://" + ip + ":1337/");
            } else if (args == "webserver") {
                ipAdressenLijst.Add("http://" + ip + ":1337/start/");
                ipAdressenLijst.Add("http://" + ip + ":1337/stop/");
            }
        }
    }
    return ipAdressenLijst;
}
```

Your Webserver.cs code should look like this to handle the incoming array of URIs.

```
public class WebServer {
    string[] Uris;
    public WebServer(Func<HttpListenerRequest, string> sendResponse, IEnumerable<string> ipAdressenLijst)
    {
        Uris = ipAdressenLijst.ToArray();
    }
}
```

In `Main` function in Program.cs, your call should look like

```
WebServer ws = new WebServer(SendResponse, IPs.GetIPs("webserver"));
```

There is a lot of guess work on my side, as not all information is available in your question.. Let me know if that makes sense and works for you

Comment: Please tell me what information you need more... I think the functions looks alright now, so let me try it out...

Comment: I get some errors now, if you need more code I can add them to the opening post...

Comment: `WebServer ws = new WebServer(SendResponse, IPs.GetIPs("program"));` now gives this: `Error CS1503 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'method group' to 'string[]'` and `Error CS1503 Argument 2: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>' to 'System.Func<System.Net.HttpListenerRequest, string>'`.

Comment: @Alex You haven't talked anything about what is `SendResponse` in your question. If you tell me what is its type, I can update the answer with that information

Comment: I updated the opening post. It's in program.cs under main().

Comment: I fixed those errors I got, I have a couple of new errors now.

Comment: @Alex I have fixed that issue in my answer now.